# DensityHistogram label/display values in Mathematica 8

Tags: plotting, text, histograms, labeling, numerical-value

I'm trying to make a `DensityHistogram` in *Mathematica 8* that overlays the histogram values for each location.  What I want is for the value of each square to be displayed over it always (i.e. not in the `StatusArea` or as a `Tooltip`).  For instance, if you run this code in *Mathematica*, one of the squares will have a value of 23, and I'd like that value overlaid on that square, and then the same for all the other non-zero values (I don't need a bunch of 0's).

```
a = {{1.6, 314.1592}, {0.8, 63.6172}, {0.4, 113.0973}, {1, 19.6349}, {1, 19.6349}, 
     {1, 50.2654}, {1, 490.8738}, {1, 19.6349}, {0.045, 17.5}, {0.3, 80}, {0.06, 120}, 
     {1, 100}, {1,78.5398}, {0.06, 120}, {1, 7.0685}, {0.33, 126.6768}, {1, 369.8361}, 
     {0.0008, 0.09}, {1, 1134.1149}, {0.06, 64}, {0.08, 120}, {1, 113.0973}, {0.19, 600},
     {1, 283.5287}, {0.00217,14}, {1, 201.0619}, {0.64, 283.5287}, {2, 1520.5308}, {60, 31.4159},
     {0.3, 10}, {1, 201.0619}, {1, 283.5287}, {2, 12.5663}, {1, 506.7074}, {0.35, 176.7145},
     {0.05, 1.1309}, {2, 1520.5308}, {0.7, 28.2743}, {1, 49}, {1, 100}, {1, 706.8583},
     {1, 706.8583}, {8, 3848.451}, {1, 50.2654}, {1, 50.2654}, {1, 314.1592}, {1, 314.1592},
     {1, 314.1592}, {1, 314.1592}, {1, 1140.0918}, {2, 314.1592}, {2, 314.1592}, 
     {1.5, 314.1592}, {1, 23.7582}, {1, 15.2053}, {0.02, 0.415}, {1.5, 314.1592}, 
     {1, 254.469}, {0.02, 0.415}, {1, 346.3605}, {0.5, 254.469}, {1, 95.0331}}

DensityHistogram[ a, {{{.0001, .001, .01, .1, 1, 10, 100}}, 
                      {{.01, .1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000}}}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
                  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][1 - #] &), 
                  ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Thin], BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"},
                  Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Histogram"},
                  Ticks -> {
                    Table[{10^k, Superscript[10, k]}, {k, -4, 4}], 
                    Table[{10^k, Superscript[10, k]}, {k, -2, 4}]}, 
                  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
                  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, Above] &)]
```

I'm not sure if I'm using `LabelingFunction` correctly, probably not.  I'd also like to see the relevant values on the axes histograms, if possible.

Comment: There is a comment at the docs that says _"Use automatic labeling by values through Tooltip and StatusArea:"_. So probably LabelingFunction[] does not support what you want

Comment: Ok, if that is the case, what is the best way to go about displaying the values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ChartElementFunction`:

**For Version 9:**

```
f[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, a_ , b_] := 
                 {Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, RoundingRadius -> 0.2], 
                 Text[Style[Length@a, Large, Bold, Black], Mean /@ {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}]}

DensityHistogram[a, {{{.0001, .001, .01, .1, 1, 10, 100}}, {{.01, .1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000}}},
 ChartElementFunction -> f,
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][1 - #] &), 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Thin],
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
 Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Histogram"}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[{10^k, Superscript[10, k]}, {k, -4, 4}], 
           Table[{10^k, Superscript[10, k]}, {k, -2, 4}]}, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**For Version 8 (but greater than 8.0):**

```
d= DensityHistogram[ a, {{{.0001, .001, .01, .1, 1, 10, 100}}, {{.01, .1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000}}}, 
    ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][1 - #] &), 
    ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Thin], 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
    Ticks -> {Table[{10^k, Superscript[10, k]}, {k, -4, 4}], 
              Table[{10^k, Superscript[10, k]}, {k, -2, 4}]}, 
    Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, Mesh -> True, 
    ImageSize -> 600] // FullForm;
makeText[{a_, l_List}] := Text[Style[a, Large, Bold, Black], Mean /@ Transpose[#]] & /@ l
epilog = makeText /@ Cases[d, Tooltip[a_, b_, ___] :> 
         {b, Cases[a, RectangleBox[c__] :> {c}, Infinity]}, Infinity];

DensityHistogram[a, {{{.0001, .001, .01, .1, 1, 10, 100}}, {{.01, .1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000}}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][1 - #] &), 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Thin], 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
 Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Histogram"}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[{10^k, Superscript[10, k]}, {k, -4, 4}], 
           Table[{10^k, Superscript[10, k]}, {k, -2, 4}]}, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Epilog -> epilog, LabelingFunction -> None]
```

Comment: Looks cool!  I copied your code but must be doing something wrong.  I just get 0's in the fields.  I'll keep messing with it, but if there's something I'm doing wrong, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: @iwantmyphd81 Probably you forgot to define your data (list `a = ...`)`

Comment: Just checked, my list is there and defined properly.

Comment: @iwantmyphd81 `ChartElementFunction` was first introduced in Version 7, but it seems that they modified it in V9 to pass the data points in each region. In version 8 this feature isn't present, so it isn't able to calculate the results. sorry.

Comment: @iwantmyphd81 See edit please

Comment: much better!  This just about works.  The only thing is when I run it, the code displays the decimal along with the integer part of the number (e.g. 23.0 vs. 23).  Sorry to be nit-picky, is there a way to suppress the decimals?  Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I used `IntegerPart` inside `Text[Style[a, Large, Bold, Black]` to get rid of the decimal points, so it now reads: `Text[Style[IntegerPart[a], Large, Bold, Black]`.  Thanks!